# rails does not apply JavaScript to appended items in remote true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have this code below and when I click on the pagination it appends parent but without any JavaScript added ? I tried to put the scripts on js file but no use , the only way it works is in the js.erb file but this will lead to duplicate coding and this has a huge impact on the performance and the rest of the code.

```
<style>
.parent {
width:100%
height:100%
border: 2px dotted green; }
.replies-div {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
}
</style>

<div class="parent">
<% @replies.each do |x| %>
<div class="replies-div">
<%= x.content %>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>
<%= paginate @replies, remote: true %>
    <script>
$(".replies-div").css("background-color","red");
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you style `replies-div` directly with css instead of through JS ? Also there is probably a way to trigger the JS `on change` but I am too bad with JS to tell

Comment: actually js is not apply on dynamically updated DOM try this 
`$(document).find(".replies-div").css("background-color","red");` let me know if it contain any issues

Comment: Tried it but still ....@uzaif the problem is I have a bunch of code associated with it so like on("click") and such so this is of no use unfortunately